# How to build and run an Xcode project from source code bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode

I forked a repository from GitHub. I cloned it and got a copy on my laptop. Now I opened the folder and there's no .xcodeproj file. There's a few swift files, a base.Iproj folder with the Launchscreen.xib and main.storyboard files and info.plist file. 
How do I go about putting all these files together in one Xcode project?

Comment: create a new empty project, add the downloaded files to your empty project, Move all the files in base lproj from downloaded project to your empty project, Make sure you add them all to Xcode (not just copying files to physical location) then clean and build. Fix all the missing links issue and you should be good to go. You cant build project without .xcodepro

Comment: Create a new project (select language Swift) and replace all files and build.

Comment: Thank you, Sandeep! I dragged and dropped all the files from the downloaded project to the empty project. I didn't delete the old files (that come by default in the Xcode empty project). I am getting this error -

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: @harshita-arora : Try clean and build. There must be errors in your project solve them one by one. Like file not added to compile source or file not added to project etc etc

Comment: The only error that appears every time is because there are 2 app delegate files. 
And every time I delete the default app delegate file, Xcode shows 20 errors. 
What to do now?